# Page Breaks in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor5

I've added a page break in my CKEditor field. When I output the field in my template it dumps everything in the field. How do I withhold the content after the page break?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
{{entry.myCKEditorField|split('<div class="page-break" style="page-break-after:always;">')|first()|raw}}

{{entry.myCKEditorField|split('<div class="page-break" style="page-break-after:always;">')|last()|raw}}
```